# Ошибка при компиляции java

Tags: java, ssl, java-8

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: SSLPoke (Unsupported major.minor version 52.0)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Данная ошибка подразумевает, что java 8 не поддерживается. Но я установил и 7 с 6, и в path указывал те версии перед компиляцией, все равно та же ошибка.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Для начала напишите что Вы делаете, как пытаетесь компилировать?

Comment: Изначально у меня проблемы были с SSL сертификатами, и для их решения я воспользовался SSLPoke которое нашел в просторах интернета.

Comment: в настройках проекта нужно включить поддержку java 8

Answer (score 2):

Данная ошибка означает, что библиотека, содержащая класс SSLPoke скомпилирована в Java 8, а ваш проект настроен на более старую версию Java.

Answer (score 0):

Выберите 7 java в настройках проекта.